# How to start Eclipse when Windows 10 starts

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, ide, windows-10

I have recently upgraded to Windows 10, and used to have the Eclipse application in my Startup folder. This has now been replaced with a section in Task Manager, and I cannot add Eclipse to this.

Has anyone got round this issue?

Comment: This link should be helpful http://tunecomp.net/add-app-to-startup/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The user startup folder in Windows 10 is located by default at `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`. Add a shortcut to the program you would like to execute on startup to this folder (in your case Eclipse), and then it should run the next time that you restart. For more details, see [Add App to Startup Windows 10](http://tunecomp.net/add-app-to-startup/).